# Create error in angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs, scala, playframework

This is my angular controller:

```
app.controller("custctrl",["$scope","Restangular",function($scope,Restangular){
$scope.createcust=function(){
Restangular.all("customer").post($scope.cust);
console.log($scope.cust);
};
}]);
```

In the console I can find the object but the insertion failed and I get this error:

angular.js:10765 POST http://localhost:9000/customer 400 (Bad Request)

I'm using a modal and this is a part of my code:

```
<div  id="inputModalCust" class="modal fade" ng-controller="custctrl" >
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                            <h4 class="modal-title"><Strong><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Customer </Strong></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                          <form  class="form-horizontal" >
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="input" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="cust.identity.companyName" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="input" class="col-md-2 control-label">logo</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="cust.logo" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="input" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="cust.linkset" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="input" class="col-md-2 control-label">Phone</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="cust.colorSet" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                               <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="input" class="col-md-2 control-label">Website</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="cust.webSite" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="input" class="col-md-2 control-label">Category</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="cust.category" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="input" class="col-md-2 control-label">Time zone</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="cust.timeZone" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"> 
                                </div>
                            </div>                        

                        </form>
                        </div>
                         <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" ><i class="gi gi-remove_2"></i> <Strong>Close</Strong></button>
                            <button type="button"  data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="createcust()"><i class="gi gi-floppy_saved" ></i><Strong> Save</Strong></button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the response is telling you the data you are sending is incorrect (status 400)

Comment: but i tested the same data with postman and it's worked fine

Comment: Are you doing the `POST` call from the same server - same host and port? or the port is different? If so then this is treated as CORS, that means your backend has to return 200 OK for preflight `OPTIONS` call, check your developer tools network tab to see what's the method used for call

Comment: and postman is not under CORS restrictions

Comment: it's ok thank you for your replay. the problem was a wrong field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I had a wrong field, timeZone is an int this is why I had to change the type here from text to number:

```
   <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="input" class="col-md-2 control-label">Time zone</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="**number**" ng-model="cust.timeZone" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
```